# Sinon how to stub dom element 'getelementbyid'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, sinon, enzyme

How to stub dom element, I use `js dom` and `sinon`? how to stub document element with id.

**Method**

```
window.identityServer = (function () {
        const identityServer = {
            getModel () {
                const modelJson = document.getElementById('modelJson')
                const encodedJson = typeof modelJson.textContent !== undefined ? modelJson.textContent : modelJson.innerHTML
            },
        }
        return identityServer
    })()
```

**Test**

```
beforeEach(() => {
        sinon.stub(document, 'getElementById').returns({textContent: 's'})

        sinon.stub(window, 'identityServer')
    })
```

**error :**
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null`

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the id?

`sinon.stub(document, "getElementById").withArgs("modelJson").returns({textContent: "s'})`

I stub the document without id before, but the error message is `s.getElementsByTagName is not a function`